# How to show pdf from one controller to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of pdf that is being rendered by one controller.

Now when I click on the edit button it should show that pdf in iframe. I am able to do that but its only showing the first pdf and not another one.

Tried to use tempdata but not working id is not being passed from one controller to another.

```
var id =TempData["query"] ;
var ID = Convert.ToInt32(id);

var filesCollection = obj.GetFiles();

var query = (from f in filesCollection
    select f.FileId).First();
var convertquery = Convert.ToInt32(query);

string filename = (from f in filesCollection
    where f.FileId == ID
    select f.FilePath).Single();
string contentType = "application/pdf";
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
return File (fs, contentType);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling the `First()` method on the collection.

What you should do is, pass the unique file id and query your collection with that id and return that.

```
public ActionResult GetFile(int id)
{
   var f= obj.GetFiles.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.FileId ==id);
   if(f!=null)
   {
      // return the file stream
   }
   // return something else
}
```

When you call from the edit screen, make sure to pass the Unique id for a file.

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("GetFile","YourControllerName", new {id=14})" 
                                            style="width:718px; height:700px;" ></iframe>
```

Replace `14` with a valid unique file Id ( may be it is a property value of your view's view model)

Comment: I am getting a null value. this is what i have now

Comment: var filesCollection = obj.GetFiles();
            var f = filesCollection.FirstOrDefault(s => s.FileId == id);
            if (f != null)
            {

Comment: is `f` null ? That means you do not have a item in `filesCollection` with FileId as the value you have in Id variable. Are you sure you are passing the correct id ? Put a breakpoint in your code and inspect the variable values.

Comment: Yes f is null. public ActionResult Index(string FileId)
            {
           

            var filesCollection = obj.GetFiles();
            //var q = (from f in filesCollection
                   // select f.FileId);
            //int ID = Convert.ToInt32(q);

            var query = (from a in
                            filesCollection
                         select a.FileId).ToList();

            Session["mId"] = query;
            return View(filesCollection);

           
            }

Comment: ^^ this is what I have for my index page and trying to pass that id to my getpdf page now

Comment: So it is clear that you are not passing the correct Id to the GetFile method..

Comment: var query = (from f in filesCollection
                        select f.FileId).FirstOrDefault();
                         

            Session["mId"] = query;
            return View(filesCollection);

Comment: ^^ When I do that i get F! = null and goes through the loop.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow what you are saying. Can you add the relevant details ( your current code  and expected behavior and actual behaviour) to the question with proper code formatting.

Comment: But the ID is always equal to 1 don't know why thats happening. Its because of first(). What do i do for that?

Comment: You need to show us how you are showing the link/iframe to this action method from your edit screen. Show the relevant code with proper formatting please

Comment: public ActionResult Index(string FileId)
            {
             var filesCollection = obj.GetFiles();
            //var q = (from f in filesCollection
            // select f.FileId);
            //int ID = Convert.ToInt32(q);

            var query = (from f in filesCollection
                        select f.FileId).FirstOrDefault();
                         

            Session["mId"] = query;
            return View(filesCollection);
 }  This is my Index method now I want to pass that ID in my GETPDF method so I can show it in iframe.

Comment: CODE IS BELOW  <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetPDF")" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: You need to pass an id. See my updated answer.

Comment: I am still getting only one id

Comment: You need to show us the code where you are calling it